# Compiling Static FFMPEG Binary

Tags: static, ffmpeg, osx-yosemite

I cannot seem to compile a static build of FFMPEG. All of my attempts result with a ffmpeg binary that  looks for libraries outside of the binary. Does anything stand out in my configure options? 
Some further details - `On OSX 10.10.5 and  Xcode7`. I used homebrew to build all of the dependencies in `'/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8/'` I then used the same compile options that the homebrew install used and extended it with further options.

Compiling goes without a hitch. The only issue being the ffmpeg binary is not static. I tried specifying `--disable--share --enable-static` with no luck (though i've read that these are on by default and do not need explicit specification)

### ## Compile Options ##

```
  ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8/  -enable-gpl --enable-    pthreads --disable-libfaac --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffplay --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libquvi --enable-libsoxr --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openssl --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libzmq --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-avresample --disable-openssl --enable-opengl --disable-nvenc --enable-filters --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect && make -j        4 && make install`
```

### ## Compiled FFMPEG Binary ##

```
./ffmpeg -buildconf 
ffmpeg version N-75841-g5911eeb Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8/ --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --disable-libfaac --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffplay --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libquvi --enable-libsoxr --enable-libssh --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openssl --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-videotoolbox --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libzmq --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-avresample --disable-openssl --enable-opengl --disable-nvenc --enable-filters --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetectlibavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
libavcodec     57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
libavformat    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 10.100 /  6. 10.100
libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100

configuration:
--enable-gpl
--enable-pthreads
--disable-libfaac
--disable-libfdk-aac
--enable-ffplay
--enable-fontconfig
--enable-libfreetype
--enable-frei0r
--enable-libbluray
--enable-libbs2b
--enable-libcaca
--enable-libquvi
--enable-libsoxr
--enable-libssh
--enable-libvidstab
--enable-libvorbis
--enable-libvpx
--enable-libopenjpeg
--enable-openssl
--enable-libopus
--enable-librtmp
--enable-libschroedinger
--enable-libspeex
--enable-libtheora
--enable-videotoolbox
--enable-libwebp
--enable-libx265
--enable-libzmq
--disable-shared
--enable-static
--enable-avresample
--disable-openssl
--enable-opengl
--disable-nvenc
--enable-filters
--arch=x86_64
--enable-runtime-cpudetect
```

---

Is there somethign glaringly wrong in my configuration? Is it a licensing thing - where certain libraries wont compile statically? 
I deeply appreciate any guidance in compiling a static ffmpeg binary.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe take a look at: https://github.com/stvs/ffmpeg-static Also, IDK which libraries you're having trouble with, but remember [the OS X system libraries cannot be statically linked](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html).

Comment: what libraries is it looking for externally when you run it?

Comment: If I try running the compiled binary without the libraries in /usr/local/lib I get
`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/NNinkovic/repo/FFmpeg/./ffmpeg
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: you could try adding --disable-sdl I suppose